# RxJava2/Retrofit2 - Handling null for 204 PUT and DELETE requests

Tags: rx-java, retrofit2, okhttp

So, I am working with an API that is clearly defined and is designed to not return a payload body on `DELETE` and `PUT` operations.

This was acceptable in Rx 0.X and Rx 1.x. Now I'm updating to Rx 2 and having an existential crisis with how I should handle the null values.  The content-length and body are of course null causing:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Null is not a valid element
   at io.reactivex.internal.queue.SpscLinkedArrayQueue.offer(SpscLinkedArrayQueue.java:68)
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.onNext(ObservableObserveOn.java:116)
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.onNext(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:63)
```

in the doOnNext.

I've seen many people suggest `Optional<>` but I need to support Java7 as well for use case reasons.  I attempted back-porting but I couldn't quite get it to work.  I also don't want to bloat and import the Guava library for their version.

I also noticed flatMap may also help me handle this opposed to map and I'm reading up on the differences.

Currently I have a very crude, OkHttp3 Interceptor that will check the status, check if the payload is empty, and add dummy content which just feels so wrong.

I've also tried to add a convert factory.

Can anyone offer suggestions and guide me on what the proper path is? Sure, the API can change, but 204 isn't supposed to have a payload by virtue of it's definition as an HTTP status code.

#### Relevant Dependencies

```
compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
     exclude module: 'okhttp'
} 
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'

compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.5'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'com.trello.rxlifecycle2:rxlifecycle:2.0.1'
compile 'com.trello.rxlifecycle2:rxlifecycle-components:2.0.1'
```

Comment: Are you using Retrofit and you have forgot to mention it?

Comment: Yes...thank you....I updated the question to reflect that

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to declare your request method  in `Retrofit` like:

```
@DELETE(...)
Call<Void> deleteFile(...args);
```

In RxJava your `Observable` has to be typed:

```
@DELETE(...)
Observable<Response<Void>> deleteFile(...args);
```

In `onNext()` or `doOnNext()` you will receive the `Response` normally, if the request is successful.

Having `Void` will not send the response body to the converter for further deserialization. All empty-response `Call`s should be typed as `Void`.

Comment: +1 I hadn't even thought about the Response<Void> path.  I figured it would be similar to null.  Everything is happy now.  I appreciate the assist.

Comment: The problem with this is even when an error is thrown, the subcribe block is still called. On error with a Void response, the throwable error block never hits

Comment: You should use `Completable` instead of `Observable<Response<Void>>`

Comment: What if frontend needs to show error message?

Comment: You saved my day. I was using.. okhttp's Response class. we should use below code.
` Single<retrofit2.Response<Void>>`

Answer (score 14):

Since you have a RxJava2 and retrofit 2, you could use a more readable way of describing what it is you really want from an endpoint using a [`Completable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/v2.0.4/src/main/java/io/reactivex/CompletableObserver.java).

`Completable` by design returns only `onComplete()` and `onError(Exception)` so you know what is going on right the moment you see it(you only care about execution not the return value) and not wonder what will be under `Response<Void>`.

So your endpoint call should look like:

```
@DELETE(...)
Completable deleteFile(...args);
```

More types are supported, see the [Retrofit 2 RxJava 2 Adapter](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter#usage) page.`Single` is one that stands out in terms of api calls.

Comment: Thank you! This is the correct answer. It has no flaw which @MobileMon found in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

For somebody who's still searching for the answer: replacing Void to some empty class solved my problem. Like this:

```
class EmptyResponse {}
```

and just use this class instead of Void

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use-case below could be another [solution](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2867#issuecomment-616904202).

It could be handled with Okhttp3 Interceptor.

```
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.MediaType
import okhttp3.Response
import okhttp3.ResponseBody

object EmptyBodyInterceptor : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
        if (response.isSuccessful.not() || response.code().let { it != 204 && it != 205 }) {
            return response
        }

        if ((response.body()?.contentLength() ?: -1) >= 0) {
            return response.newBuilder().code(200).build()
        }

        val emptyBody = ResponseBody.create(MediaType.get("text/plain"), "")

        return response
            .newBuilder()
            .code(200)
            .body(emptyBody)
            .build()
    }
}
```